# sap.m.Table with invisible rows does not show "No data"

Tags: sapui5

I have a `sap.m.Table` where I map an array of objects (the rows)
I do not show some row by `visible` property in the `sap.m.ColumnListItem`.

All works fine but when the table does not contain any row this is the result:
[image]

The text "No data" does not show and I see a simple empty table :(

This is the result I want to achieve:
[image]
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is use Filter instead of hiding a row by formatter.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a situation where you've bound the Table's items aggregation but are just suppressing the row display with the visible property. The Table still has items bound, and therefore won't display the "no data" text because there is data. This is correct. The snippet here is what you describe you're doing.

```js
var oTable = sap.m.Table("salesarea", {
  columns : [
    new sap.m.Column({
      header : new sap.m.Text({text: "Place"})
    })
  ],
  items: {
    path: "/places",
    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      visible : false,
      cells : [
        new sap.m.Text({text: "{name}"})
      ]
    })
  }
});
oTable
.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  places: [
    { name: "Manchester" },
    { name: "Liverpool" },
    { name: "Leeds" },
    { name: "Sheffield" }
  ]
}))
.placeAt("content");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
alert("Table has " + oTable.getItems().length + " items");
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: My opinion is that the user not know if the table has not data or if the table has rows but they are not visible. 
Simply user not see rows. ---> he must see "No Data"

Comment: I agree, but if you're going to explicitly hide data from the user, it's then your responsibility to tell him that.

Comment: I agree with @qmacro. But taking a step back, if you don't want to display (all / certain) records, why not simply use a filter instead of hiding table rows?

Comment: I have opened this Q. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807451/custom-filter-null
Yours is a good suggestion, but I have some problem..

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer or do you need more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It should show the text by default. Two guesses:

Your data may contain a single (or even multiple) empty entry so that a ColumnListItem gets rendered but has no visible content.

You misconfigured one of this properties belonging to `sap.m.Table` resp. `sap.m.ListBase`:

- noDataText : string (no need to set this, there is a default)
- showNoData : boolean (default: true)

GL
Chris